# MYSQL show all entries sorted by 2 columns random on one column

Tags: mysql, sorting, group-by, sql-order-by

We are looking to return rows of a query as groups and displaying all entries of the group in the sort order. Randomly based on the `set_id`... and then in order by the `sort_id`.

So, randomly it will show:

> Carl,
>   Phil,
>   Wendy,
>   Tina,
>   Rick,
>   Joe

or

> Tina,
>   Rick,
>   Joe,
>   Carl,
>   Phil,
>   Wendy

This query is always showing Tina/Rick/Joe first

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY set_id, rand()
```

Any help would be appreciated

```
+---------+--------+-------+----------+

| id      | set_id | name  | sort_id  |

+---------+--------+-------+----------+

|       1 | AA     |Rick   |      2   |

|       2 | BB     |Carl   |      1   |

|       3 | AA     |Joe    |      3   |

|       4 | AA     |Tina   |      1   |

|       5 | BB     |Phil   |      2   |

|       6 | BB     |Wendy  |      3   |

+---------+--------+-------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need a random comma separated name list this will do the trick. 
This will keep the groups and the correct sorting within the group.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 GROUP_CONCAT(Table_names_rand.names) as names
FROM (

  SELECT
   *
  FROM ( 

    SELECT 
     GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY sort_id) as names
    FROM 
     Table1
    GROUP BY
     set_id
 )
   AS Table1_names
  ORDER BY 
   RAND()
)
 AS Table_names_rand
```

**Result**

```
|                         names |
|-------------------------------|
| Carl,Phil,Wendy,Tina,Rick,Joe |
```

or

```
|                         names |
|-------------------------------|
| Tina,Rick,Joe,Carl,Phil,Wendy |
```

demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/487ac9/9

if you need random names as records output.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 Table1.name
FROM
 Table1
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 
   GROUP_CONCAT(Table_names_rand.names) as names
  FROM (

    SELECT
     *
    FROM ( 

      SELECT 
       GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY sort_id) as names
      FROM 
       Table1
      GROUP BY
       set_id
   )
     AS Table1_names
   ORDER BY 
     RAND()
 )
   AS Table_names_rand
) 
  AS Table_names_rand
ORDER BY
 FIND_IN_SET(name, Table_names_rand.names)
```

**Result**

```
|  name |
|-------|
|  Carl |
|  Phil |
| Wendy |
|  Tina |
|  Rick |
|   Joe |
```

or

```
|  name |
|-------|
|  Tina |
|  Rick |
|   Joe |
|  Carl |
|  Phil |
| Wendy |
```

demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/487ac9/28

Answer (score 0):

If we strip away the randomness of the gorup ordering, your query would look like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    products 
ORDER BY 
    set_id, 
    sort_id;
```

The ordering by `set_id` is necessary to "group" the results, without really grouping them. You do not want to group them, because then the rows with the same group would be aggregated, meaning that only one row per group would be put out.

Since you only want to randomize the groups, you need to write another query that assigns a random number to each group, like the one below:

```
SELECT
    set_id,
    RAND() as 'rnd'
FROM
    products
GROUP BY
    set_id
```

The `GROUP BY` clause makes sure, that each group is only selected once. The resultset will look like this:

| set_id | priority |

+--------+---------+

|     AA   |   0.21   |

|    BB    |    0.1   |

With that result we can then randomize the output, by combining both queries with a `JOIN` on the `set_id` field. This will add the randomly generated number from the second query to the result set of the first query and therefore extend the static `set_id` with the randomized, but still for all group members equal, `rnd`:

```
SELECT
    products.*
FROM
    products
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            set_id,
            RAND() as 'rnd'
        FROM
            products
        GROUP BY
            set_id
    ) as rnd ON rnd.set_id = products.set_id
ORDER BY
    rnd.rnd,
    products.set_id,
    products.sort_id;
```

Keep in mind, that it is important to still group on `products.set_id`, because it may be possible that two groups get the same random number assigned. If the result would not be ordered by `products.set_id` those groups members would then be merged.